# Desktop theme is loading in both mobile and desktop

Tags: theme, css, mobile, exception, package

I want to set two different theme[image]s for desktop view and mobile view. After all configuration also the mobile theme is not coming in mobile view , instead its loading the desktop theme.

My mobile theme is here : mobile view -  skin/frontend/default/iphonegfbs/css/iphone.css

Desktop theme is here :desktop view - skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to understand the `design fallback mechanism` of magento

when you load exception theme then magento searches files in exception theme.

then it will search in main theme in your case (DESKTOP theme).

and after that it will search files in `base/default` theme.

if you still have problem then check all this settings in store scope or website scope